# What use cases would benefit from a faster RNG?

Tags: random-number-generator

The paper “[Explicit Two-Source Extractors and Resilient Functions](http://phys.org/news/2016-05-method-random-cybersecurity.html)” (PDF) by Eshan Chattopadhyay and David Zuckerman is described by some as being a technological leap in RNG – opposed to slow and incremental benefits over time.

What benefits would a faster RNG have for cryptography in general? Does this make some formerly implausible scenarios possible?

Comment: one time pads need lots of randomness, so if you were using that to stream protected data, the generation rate will determine your bandwidth.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This paper isn't about a faster RNG, and it's mostly only of interest in a computer science context rather than in an applied cryptographic context. These results reduce the theoretical requirements needed from two weak sources of randomness in order to combine them into a source of true randomness. However, in the applied world, we already have "enough" — a few bytes can seed a CSPRNG that will generate effectively infinite computationally-random bytes.

When systems today fall over due to randomness issues, it's usually due to systems-engineering failures: a good RNG wasn't used (despite them being widely and easily available), or not enough initial randomness was seeded (e.g., `/dev/urandom` on an embedded device), or a virtual machine was copied and restarted with the same initial random seed. These classes of problems aren't solved by improving our sources of randomness.

To your question directly, a faster RNG isn't of much practical use. A stream cipher seeded with enough randomness is effectively a DRBG, and can produce random bits extremely quickly — far more quickly than is needed for the overwhelming majority of use-cases. The operations that *use* that randomness typically execute far more instructions than do the operations to generate it.

Thomas Ptacek's [response to this story on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11722504) is how I expect most crypto people feel about this.

Comment: Recreating a secure random objects with fresh entropy (in a loop) should probably in the list. If anything mucks up an entropy pool it's those kind of decisions.

Comment: "a few bytes can seed a CSPRNG that will generate effectively infinite computationally-random bytes." for sufficiently large values of "few".

Answer (score 4):

[Stephen correctly points](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/35407/12164) out that the paper isn't about RNGs.  I'll take the question literally, though, and remark that there are *non-cryptographic* applications that could potentially benefit from faster CSPRNG.  Non-cryptographic users of PRNGs have to balance two concerns:

- Speed
- Biases

Faster generators tend to have more statistical biases, while less biased ones tend to be slower.  Building a faster cryptographic PRNG would, effectively, give you more speed without introducing biases (or at least no biases observable to a computationally-bound adversary).

There are also PRNGs that, despite not being intended for cryptographic use, use cryptographic designs as part of a correctness argument.  See for example [Claessen and Pałka's splittable pseudo random number generators](http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/183348/local_183348.pdf), which use cryptographic components not for security, but rather for *correctness*.  This is an interesting elaboration of the previous point, however: correctness is lack of bias.  But clearly, this is a case where faster crypto would allow faster non-cryptographic RNGs.